# R compressively saving large data frames to hard drive

Tags: r, csv, compression, gzip

I need to save some large `dataframes` in R to hard drive. Since the dimension of each `DF` is quite large (~>50K rows and >50 columns) and I have more than 200K of them, I would like to save them compressively in order to save some hard drive space.

So far, I tried a couple of types such like `.CSV`, `rds` (`compress = "gzip"`), which takes ~`60MB` and `20 MB`, respectively. I am wondering if there are some alternative ways to compress them more efficiently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do much better than `saveRDS()` unless your data have some very particular structure.  You can get a slight (~10%) advantage by using one of the alternative compression options; below, I go from 12.7M to 10.5M by using `xz` compression rather than `gzip` (in my example the CSV is 43M).

Set up example:

```
set.seed(101)
m <- matrix(runif(5e4*50),ncol=50)
```

(This is a matrix, not a data frame: I doubt it will make much difference but you could experiment.)

Write CSV file:

```
write.csv(m,file="tmp.csv")
s_csv <- file.info("tmp.csv")["size"]
```

Try out compression options:

```
c_opts <- c("gzip","bzip2","xz")
ss <- sapply(c_opts,
        function(c) {
          saveRDS(m,compress=c,file="tmp.rds")    
          return(file.info("tmp.rds")["size"])
})
```

Combine, convert to MB:

```
unlist(c(csv=s_csv,ss))/2^20
##  csv.size  gzip.size bzip2.size    xz.size 
##   43.28464   12.69796   11.32605   10.46269
```